# Python Kivy Is Printing numbers while importing it

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I just installed Kivy in my virtualenv

I installed it using  `pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip`

My dependencies

```
Python 2.7.10
Kivy==1.10.1.dev0
Cython==0.26.1
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
```

When I tried to run it in my terminal 
using command `from kivy.app import App`

Its printing integers recursively  I have attached screenshot below[image: The Numbers Are Getting Printed I continuously I have No Reason]

Thanks in advance!!

I Have Raised A GIT ISSUE ALSO :- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5515

Comment: looks like someone forgot to remove the "print" statements before committing...

Comment: lol its printing from 15 mins :D

Comment: try to reinstall it and follow the steps of https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy has no support to python 2.7 so kindly update your python to 3x then reinstall kivy I guess it will work!!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot I have done the same I upgraded my python to 3x and then it worked!!

Comment: Actually we still support python2.7, and a lot of people still use it, we'll certainly stop supporting it in some not so distant future, but we do not expect such issues on any python version.

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose a workaround: it's to turn off printing from python during imports. It's lame but will fix in while they're fixing the forgotten print properly:

```
import sys

def write(x):
    pass
saved = sys.stdout.write
sys.stdout.write = write

from kivy.app import App  # works for any import that uses stdout to print stuff

sys.stdout.write = saved
```

just save `sys.stdout.write`, then override it with a method that does nothing, then import. Restore standard output after importing.

I've tested it with a custom module that prints stuff when imported, and it suppresses the prints. If it doesn't work, the same thing can be tried with `sys.stderr.write`

Comment: Is kivy meant to run like that on import though? In OP's comment, it's been running for 15 mins, won't that mean their script is basically locked regardless of not seeing the print, or does it automatically spawn a thread/process?

Comment: Yes Its locking my process its taking forever to load now. Thanks for the answer !! That line is executing from a long time. Is there any way to async the import ?

Comment: @saditya If that's running in the main process, it may never break out of whatever loop its in. It looks like you're using a development version, is there not a stable version you could install instead?

Comment: @roganjosh version is a stable one cause its written in the official docs site .   look here : https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html

Comment: @saditya I'd say it's exhibiting clear signs of instability :P Downgrade a version and try?